# What is the term for Italian words that contain exactly the 5 vowels AEIOU?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I am looking for a term to indicate Italian words that contain exactly the 5 vowels (A,E,I,O,U), each one exactly once. The number of consonants is not important. What is the term for these words?

Example: *[aiuole](http://italian.about.com/library/weekly/aa081303a.htm)*.

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/it.hobby.enigmi/V1fG_cQfW4o) out.

Comment: Also https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panvocalismo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved with a straightforward search online (or with a one-line script on a dictionary file).

Comment: @DaG Where can I find a dictionary file? And to me it seems that a search online is not that straightforward.

Comment: @MWijnand: It is straightforward if you searched in Italian, probably that’s a tad difficult if you just started learning the language. That said, with just a bit more googling for the same stuff in English you would have found the term for it: panvowel... a translation and search of the term in Italian leads you to whole lists of words... that’s why the question is on hold. You still have the answer in the comments but it would be nice if you edited your question so it would fit the rules since now you know enough to do so. (so they can keep the question)

Comment: If you add a Y, _trenino di Capodanno_.

Comment: In the way it is stated now, I think that the question can be reopened.

Comment: @PaoloFranchi Could you answer `panvocalismo` below? Then I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Il *panvocalismo*.

(answered by Paolo Franchi)